# Stepper motor position control

Tags: raspberry-pi, stepper-motor, pid-controller, python

i currently try to control a stepper motor to position a camera, to keep my face in the middle of the frame.
The face detection is working, and my python program(on raspberry pi 3) can determin the offset between the detected face and the middle of the cameras frame
i want to control the stepper motor to smoothly move the camera, so the face is mid frame

the problem:
i tried using a pid controller to calculate speed and direction, but when the program starts moving the motor (connected via step direction) the face detection stops(because the program is stuck in the loop to switch the step pin high/low)

is there a way to run the face detection part of the program while the stepper is moving and adjust the speed "on the fly"?

Help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Run the face detection and stepper control programs in different threads or different processes. This question would be more suited for [SO]. It should not be difficult to run two programs parallely in the raspberry PI OS. And some form of communication from the face detection program to the stepper control program.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate task to handle the motor. Then have a socket or other means of inter-task communication so that your face recognition task can send a non-blocking message. There’s probably a method in python to do this already. I don’t do python though.

Get an Arduino nano or similar and have it handle the stepper motor and talk to it via usb serial.

Comment: i do have an arduino, didn't try that yet as i thought this might work in python. would you suggest running an pid loop on the py or the arduino?
i am not sure if the communication on the arduino might interrupt the output to the stepper